# How to add a Konva component using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

I'm relatively new to React and I am getting stuck when trying to integrate [KonvaJS](https://konvajs.org) into React. I'm trying to follow the first example shown in the [Konva Overview](https://konvajs.org/docs/overview.html):

```
// first we need to create a stage
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',   // id of container <div>
  width: 500,
  height: 500
});

// then create layer
var layer = new Konva.Layer();

// create our shape
var circle = new Konva.Circle({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  radius: 70,
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4
});

// add the shape to the layer
layer.add(circle);

// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);

// draw the image
layer.draw();
```

So I created my own file `KonvaDrawer.js` which encapsulates the above code:

```
import Konva from 'konva';

function KonvaDrawer() {
    // first we need to create a stage
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',   // id of container <div>
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });
    
    // then create layer
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    
    // create our shape
    var circle = new Konva.Circle({
        x: stage.width() / 2,
        y: stage.height() / 2,
        radius: 70,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
    
    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(circle);
    
    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
    
    // draw the image
    layer.draw();
}

export default KonvaDrawer;
```

Then in my App.js I create the `div` with an `id="container"` as the code above mentions it needs to have a div with that id (or that's what I understand)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div id="container"></div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And finally the index.js where I call the `KonvaDrawer` function:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import KonvaDrawer from './KonvaDrawer';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    {KonvaDrawer()}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

However when I do `npm start` I get this error:

```
Stage.js:105 Uncaught Can not find container in document with id container
```

So, I'm not sure why this is happening,

All the examples that I've found online create the Konva components like this:

```
<Stage>
    <Layers>
        <Shapes>
```

For example [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/canvas-manipulation-react-konva/) and [here](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva) but I'm curious about if the way that I'm trying to do it is possible and why it's not working currently.

So, if I follow the above structure and do this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Stage, Layer, Circle} from 'react-konva';

function App() {
  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        <Circle x={window.innerWidth / 2} 
                y={window.innerHeight / 2} 
                radius={70}
                fill={'red'}
                stroke={'black'}
                strokeWidth={4}
        />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It correctly shows a red circle, but if I wanted to automate the creation of layers of something with for-loops, or create elements with Javascript, then how could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `KonvaDrawer` is just a function that creates Konva nodes directly. It can't be used as a React component (https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#overview)

So react components do not create elements (such as Konva nodes or DOM elements) directly. They just define how the page (or canvas element) should look at the end.

If you want to create elements with for-loop or other ways you just need to define your "state" of the app and the generate components from the state.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [circle, setCircles] = React.useState([{x: 10, y: 10}, {x: 100, y: 100}]);

  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        {circles.map(circle => (
          <Circle x={circle.x} 
                y={circle.y} 
                radius={70}
                fill={'red'}
                stroke={'black'}
                strokeWidth={4}
          />
        ))}
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you lavrton, is it possible for you to add a sample of what you mean on your last paragraph? I think I got lost there

Comment: I updated the answer with a small sample of "for-loop", but used "map" instead of "for-loop".